# Limesurvey - Unable to add files in email templates

Tags: email, templates, attachment, limesurvey

I use Limesurvey 2.05 on Godaddy linux. Tried with Chrome , Firefox and IE.
Ween I try to add a file on the email template, nothing happens - no error , no message. Upon saving the attachment vanishes.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks
rg

Answer (score 0):

Your buildnumber ? Because there are knowed issue
http://bugs.limesurvey.org/view.php?id=8548

Comment: The build number is 140217

Comment: That link is not publicly accessible.

Comment: You're right ... sorry fix is here : https://bugs.limesurvey.org/plugin.php?page=Source/view&id=13794 . But here : seems to be a js issue. Need console.log. AND better : use a updated version.